# Can not locate a downloaded file with empty name

Tags: filesystem, file-format

I downloaded a video using Chrome in Ubuntu by giving empty name, i.e.  `.mp4`  only. I can play using Chrome when I click on it in the download section in Chrome but I can not find this video in the folder. 
How to locate this video?

Comment: Press `Ctrl`+`H` to see hidden files in Nautilus.

Comment: fyi:  files that start with a "." do not show in normal `ls` or directory views, the "." at the start of the name makes them get treated as 'hidden' (helping to clean up your view files)

Comment: If you are using a terminal to look for the videos, use `ls -a` to show hidden files as well

Answer (score 2):

Any file/folder with name starting with a '.' will be considered  as a hidden file/folder. 
You can rename it to something else to view it.

Example: a.mp4

Use terminal to navigate to that folder and rename it.

```
$ cd <download_folder>
$ mv .mp4 a.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

`.mp4` its mean hidden in files. Click [the three line menu *"navicon"*](https://css-tricks.com/three-line-menu-navicon/) (AKA sandwich menu icon) and tick show hidden files:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Click where exactly? Please improve your answer or it will be flagged for low quality and possibly deleted.